# Spring Boot, не отображает jsp

Tags: java, jsp, spring-boot

При старте web приложения на String Boot отображается только пустая страница и в консоли: 
"Cannot forward to error page for request as the response has already been committed. As a result, the response may have the wrong status code"
Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться:
(ссылка на github https://github.com/Avvilenn/MySpringBootApp )
вот структура проекта:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Класс с методом main:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SwingBootWebApp extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

public SwingBootWebApp() {
    super();
    setRegisterErrorPageFilter(false);
}

@Override
protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
    return application.sources(SwingBootWebApp.class);
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    SpringApplication.run(SwingBootWebApp.class, args);
}
}
```

конфигурация:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class ApplicationWebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
    configurer.enable();
}

@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {

    registry.addResourceHandler(
            "/css/**",
            "/fonts/**",
            "/js/**"
    ).addResourceLocations(
            "/css/",
            "/fonts/",
            "/js/"
    ).resourceChain(true)
            .addResolver(new PathResourceResolver());

    super.addResourceHandlers(registry);
}

@Bean
public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver() {
    InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/");
    resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    return resolver;
}
```

контроллер:

```
@Controller
public class PersonController {
@Autowired
private PersonService service;

@RequestMapping("/")
public String welcome (Model model){
    List<Person> personList = service.getAll();
    model.addAttribute("PERSONS", personList);
    return "welcome";
}}
```

applicaton.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/opinion
spring.datasource.username = root
spring.datasource.password = root
spring.datasource.testWhileIdle = true
spring.datasource.validationQuery = SELECT 1
spring.jpa.show-sql = true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy =org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect =org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect

spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
```

pom.xml

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.elena.mySpringBootApp</groupId>
<artifactId>MySpringBootApp</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.1.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- MYSQL -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
        <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>


</dependencies>
```

Comment: обычно jsp находятся в `/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/` 
при этом в конфигах ставится `/WEB-INF/views/`.
А у вас jsp находятся в `resources`. Перенестие все в папку   `/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/` и должно заработать

Comment: еще уберите из зависимостей thymeleaf

Comment: Александр, спасибо, но не помогло :( перенесла, убрала... все равно:          Whitelabel Error Page

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Wed May 31 13:30:04 GMT+03:00 2017
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
/MySpringBootApp-1.0-SNAPSHOT/

Comment: на гите поправил. Вы конфиг переписали, нужно было оставить
/WEB-INF/views/

Comment: о, заработало :)) спс))

Comment: всегда пожалуйста)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавь зависимость

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

`JSP` файлы помести в субдеректорию например `views` и бин `ViewResolver`создай так:

```
@Bean
public ViewResolver viewResolver(){
    InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
    resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
    return resolver;
}
```

Выше упомянутый бин можно заменить на 2 строки в `application.properties`

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix: /WEB-INF/views/
spring.mvc.view.suffix: .jsp
```

Comment: Спасибо, сделала как вы написали, но все равно выдает ошибку:  

   Whitelabel Error Page

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Tue May 30 20:25:23 GMT+03:00 2017
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
/MySpringBootApp-1.0-SNAPSHOT/

Comment: вот ссылка на мой github    https://github.com/Avvilenn/MySpringBootApp  может так можно будет понять, что не так сделала